# Intevention image upload into mysql database in laravel showing below error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I receive below the error when i save the image into database , this my code,
Note : i used Intervention Library

Error

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException**
Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback

```
`public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required',
        'category_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
    ]);
   // $data = $request->all();
      $imageFile = $request->category_image;
      $image = Image::make($imageFile->getRealPath());
      Response::make($image->encode('jpeg'));
    $formData = array(
        'parent_id' => uniqid(),
        'category_name' => $request->category_name,
        'category_image' => $image,
        'image_name' => 'image',
        'status' => 1,
    );
    Categories::create($formData);
    return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('flash_message_success','Category added successfully...');
}`
```

Comment: I solved the issue.... thank you .

Comment: Please post your answer, as this may help to another.